# Router.go( ) page render in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, spacebars

When I hit the `/login` route as triggered below, the correct route renders, but the top of the page begins with my `template`, not my `layoutTemplate`.  I have to scroll up in order to see the `layoutTemplate` configured in the route.

```
   if(! Meteor.userId()){
        Session.set('single_post_not_logged_in', Session.get('post_id'));
        Router.go('/login');
    }
```

This is the route that gets triggerd:

```
Router.route('login', {
    path: '/login',
    layoutTemplate: 'loginLayoutTemplate',
    template: 'login_template',
    onBeforeAction: function(){
        if(Meteor.loggingIn()){
            var post_visited = Session.get('single_post_not_logged_in');
            console.log(post_visited);
            if(post_visited != undefined){
                Router.go('/post/' + post_visited);
            }

        }
        this.next();
    }
});
```

And finally, here is the layout template that the route is leaving (`layoutTemplate`) and the new layout template (`loginLayoutTemplate`)

```
<body>
    {{renderPage}}
</body>

<template name = 'layoutTemplate'>
    {{> loginButtons}}
    <a id = 'home_button' href="{{pathFor 'home'}}"><h1 id='layout_header'>snippetExchange</h1></a>
    <div id='layout_header_row_2'>
        <h2 id='layout_by_line'>valuable answers</h2> 
        <a id = 'new_post_button' href="{{pathFor 'new_post'}}">new post</a>
    </div>
    {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name = 'loginLayoutTemplate'>
    <a id = 'home_button' href="{{pathFor 'home'}}"><h1 id='layout_header'>snippetExchange</h1></a>
    <div id=''>
        <h2 id='layout_by_line'>valuable answers</h2> 
    </div>
    {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name = 'login_template'>
    <h3>please login or create an account</h3>
    {{> loginButtons}}
</template>
```

Comment: `template: login_template` but you don't have `login_template` in your HTML? Check inspector for errors. `template` will replate the `{{> yield}}` in the template defined by `layoutTemplate`

Comment: i do have a `login_template`, i included it at the bottom of my post

Comment: Weird, that shows up today but wasn't visible yesterday. Now that I re-read your question, it actually seems that the route is being rendered correctly but that the vertical scroll position is set to the top of `template`, is that correct? That's easy to fix with a template helper and some javascript but the deeper question of why eludes me.

Comment: I added the login_template code after your comment.  im confused how a template helper would be needed to fix the scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Template.login_template.onRendered(function(){
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I've been warned several times to expect a template to be rendered more times than expected. Could this cause some unexpected page scrolls?

Comment: The helper will get called many times but a given template should only be rendered once. *Unless* it's nested in an `{{#each}}`!